# 得 in sentence 没有工作的那段时间，我穷得一天只吃得起一顿饭。

Tags: grammar, meaning

Can someone explain how I can translate the second part of the sentence? I don't understand the meaning of 得 and 得起。 Thank you。

Answer (score 2):

> 我穷[**得**]一天只吃[**得**]起一顿饭。

> I was poor [**to the point of**] I [**could**] only afford to eat one meal a day

- The first **得** is placed after an adjective, which means it is a degree/ result particle that indicates [Adj + **to the point of** + degree/ result]
- The second **得** is a potential particle. There are only two potential particles. They are "得 (can)" and "不(cannot)"

吃[**得**]起一顿饭 = [**can**] afford to eat one meal

吃[**不**]起一顿饭 = [**cannot**] afford to eat one meal

*"我穷[得]一天吃[不]起一顿饭。" would mean: "I was poor to the point of couldn't afford to eat one meal a day" (maybe one meal every two day?)*

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your help. I have to more learn.